# React Native Router Flux props not passing through action

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to pass some data from my button

```
   <Button
                text="Explore"
                elementStyles={secondaryButton}
                onPress={() => Actions.dashboard({
                  demoMode: true,
                })}
                testID="button-explore"
              />
```

which is located in Example.js, to Dashboard.js

Here is my router stack located under App.js

```
<Stack key="root" hideNavBar>
              <Scene key="splash" initial component={SplashScreen} />
              ....
              <Scene key="example" component={example} />
              ....

              <Tabs key="tabbar" hideNavBar tabBarPosition="bottom" showLabel={false} tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar} swipeEnabled={false} animationEnabled={false}>
                <Scene key="dashboard" hideNavBar title="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} icon={TabBarItem} defaultIcon={Config.HOME_ICON_NAME} />
                <Scene key="history" hideNavBar title="Stats" component={History} icon={TabBarItem} defaultIcon={Config.STATS_ICON_NAME} />
                <Scene key="rewards" hideNavBar title="Points" component={Rewards} icon={TabBarItem} defaultIcon={Config.REWARDS_ICON_NAME} />
                <Scene key="profile" hideNavBar title="Profile" component={Profile} icon={TabBarItem} defaultIcon={Config.PROFILE_ICON_NAME} />
              </Tabs>
 />

            </Stack>
```

When I call this.props.demoMode under dashboard I get undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi try to add _ befor the second screen key

```
onPress={() => Actions._dashboard({
              demoMode: true,
            })}
```

something like that but if it doesn't work remove your node module folder change the router flux version , npm i again and you will be fine